# Weighing groups when there is a significant difference in sample sizes

Tags: unbalanced-classes, weighted-data

Let's say I am trying to compare average scores between three different groups. Group A contains 20 cases, group B contains 40 cases, and group C contains 300 cases.

What I originally wanted to do is weigh the cases so that each group receives equal representation, based on this:

Total cases = 360

Subgroups = 3

Weight assigned to each subgroup = 360/3 = 120

Therefore, a case in group A will be given a weight of 120/20, while a case in group C will be given a weight on 120/300.

However, since group C is an order of magnitude greater than group A, it seems that the cases in group A will be strongly overrepresented compared to what was actually sampled.

**The question:** is this acceptable, or is it something that needs to be accounted for? If so, then how? I considered randomly sampling a group of 40 cases out of group C, and then using them for the analysis (with the same weighing as described earlier).

Comment: @Ben raises good questions.  But if you're truly interested in just comparing averages of each group, why aren't you simply looking at the simple mean of each group and comparing?  Why are you weighting the groups?  Is seems like a simple ANOVA with multiple comparison tests that compares the groups mean might get you want you want, assuming the assumptions of the test hold.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know whether these samples are reliable because we don't know if they represent the larger population well.  Do all groups constitute random samples?  Furthermore, are the characteristics of the samples similar to the full population? Finally, in terms of weighting cases equally: how were the data collected?  It might make sense to weight cases when more information is considered about how cases were selected for the sample. They could be weighted equally if they were collected in the same way, but then weighting methods might vary is group A was stratified and group C was not.